# Wordpress head: After a manual including of jQuery, it is included again by a plugin... How to solve?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, include, conflict

Well, the title is pretty explanatory...

I am building a custom theme where all the fancy jQuery stuff (sliders, galleries, toggle, tooltips, etc) are manually added to head of the document, and of course, I call jQuery manually too. I prefer to work on this way instead of running wordpress plugins.

But the problem is...

There is one single plugin out there that I am not able to live without: WP-POLLS.
And what happens? As soon as I start this plugin, it calls jQuery again! And all my other stuff gets broken.

I can see 3 ways:

1 - Editing the wp-polls PHP file and remove this its jQuery calling/including

2 - Editing the wp-polls PHP file and try to insert a verification to see if jQuery is already loaded in the lines where it (re)loads/(re)includes the jQuery

3 - Learn the correct way to perform the jQuery including for my stuff that will not conflict with WP-Polls.

Any ideas, guys?
Thanks sooo much.
C.

---

### **EDIT**

I think I found the way to solve the issue.
Maybe it is not the professional method, but apparently it worked!

My WP **header.php** was:

```
<html>
<head>
   // Library
   jQuery library including

   // My own manual fancy stuff
   Slider
   Carousel
   Tooltip
   Etc

   // WP Head stuff
   wp_head();
</head>
```

Then, I changed to:

```
<html>
<head>
   // WP Head stuff
   wp_head();

   // Library (Removed OUT!)
   // jQuery library including

   // My own manual fancy stuff
   Slider
   Carousel
   Tooltip
   Etc
</head>
```

And added, to my theme **functions.php** file the following:

```
function load_my_scripts() {
if (!is_admin()) {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
} 
} add_action('init', 'load_my_scripts');
```

Now, WP-POLLS and all my fancy stuff are working fine.
But, I am not sure about...

Is there any recommendation about including wp_head() in the top of the HTML ? If I remember well it should be ever included right before the closing  tag.

And, in the **wp_register_script**, it is better to call a local jQuery library or the google one?

Thanks to all people who are watching this thread!
Regards,
C

Comment: Number 1. What's the point of doing number 2 unless you are wanting to redistribute the plugin? You know jQuery is already loaded so just comment it out from the plugin.

Comment: Hey McNab... It was my first though! But I have some other (old) sites on a wordpress multisites net work that use this plugin as well, and if I change the plugin for this new theme, the older will break... =( I am here trying to figure it out the usage of wp enqueue scripts, but got no clue yet! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to add jQuery using wp_enqueue_script() - like you did in your edit - instead of adding it manually. When using wp_enqueue_script(), no matter how many times it is called from plugins or the theme, it will only output each particular script *once*. This prevents problems like jQuery being included twice.

As for the placement of [wp_head()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head):

> Fire the 'wp_head' action. Put this template tag immediately before
>    tag in a theme template (ex. header.php, index.php).

Finally, I can't give a general answer to whether it's better to use the local jQuery library or the one from Google, but in your case, I would recommend sticking with the local one.

Comment: Thanks Janis! But, if I move the wp_head() back to its recommended place (just before the -/head- tag), my custom jQuery fancy stuff seems to see no jQuery library loaded. But the WP-POLLS is fine, since it is being initialized in the wp_head() triggers...

It's strange... I was thinking that the wp_enqueue was doing its trick for my stuff as well!

In the meantime, I will keep the wp_head() ABOVE everything in my HEAD. I can't find other way to make everything work together, as real friends... =)

Comment: That's probably because wp_head() is actually what outputs the scripts added via wp_enqueue_script(). One solution would be to add all of your scripts using wp_enqueue_script() and specify jQuery as a dependency for those scripts. Another would be to enqueue jQuery _before_ wp_head, but output the rest of your scripts after it.

Comment: Aaah... I see. I have been reading about wp_head() since yesterday and it is a neat thing. Thanks Janis. Thank you very much for you help.